# How do I create a text box on eclipse just for viewing in a scroll type menu?

Tags: android, eclipse, scroll

I am trying to make an app where you scroll(up and down) threw a list of game cheats and you can select a cheat and when you do it goes to a page in the app where you can see what the cheat code is with info about it. How do I do this? I am a complete noob.

Comment: And what have you tried? What problem have you faced?

Comment: sorry but wrong place to ask. but to give you hints, google starting Activity, passing values from one activity to another, ListView, JSON/XML, Reading XML/JSON from asset file. you will have your hands full with that. good that you are learning android dev. kudos to all android dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a listView and populate it with "cheat" objects that have text, maybe an image, and some other properties of the class. Then in the onListItemClick start a new activity and implement more detailed information about the "cheat"

There are lots of good tutorials for this stuff here:
this is a really good one: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Good luck!